# Access JBoss 7.1.1.Final using IP address

Tags: jboss7.x

How to configure standalone-full.xml to make JBoss 7.1.1.Final server accessible from remote machine using IP address?

I tried changing the bind address in interface from 127.0.0.1 to my ip address but didn't work.

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:172.x.x.x}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:172.x.x.x}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Comment: What steps have you tried so far?

Comment: I updated my question with the steps.

Answer (score 2):

I have set it like this in my standalone.xml

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
</interfaces>
```

0.0.0.0 means all interfaces

Comment: What is an appropiate configuration for a production environment?

Answer (score 0):

My `standalone.xml` looks like this:

```html
<interfaces>
  <interface name="management">
    <any-address/>
  </interface>
  <interface name="public">
    <any-address/>
  </interface>
  <interface name="unsecure">
    <any-address/>
  </interface>
</interfaces>
```

`any-address` is valid for all interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

While starting JBoss, we can also use -b 0.0.0.0 as a parameter,without having to change in standalone-full.xml. Works fine for me.